# Deny access from ips in file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is there a .htaccess command that denies access to every ip in a specific file?
Say I have a file called bans.txt (sitting next to my .htaccess file) that consists of a simple list of ips, one under the other. I want to deny access to every ip in that file. Is there a simple .htaccess command that will do it? Something like:

```
Deny from bans.txt
```

I've been searching and I don't think there is, but just checking, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is a neat way to achieve this task purely from Apache. You need to use a feature called **[RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html)**

1 - First enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `httpd.conf` to enable a `RewriteMap` called `ipmap`:

```
RewriteMap ipmap txt:/some/path/to/ipmap.txt
```

2 - Then create your text file `/some/path/to/ipmap.txt` with entries like this **listing all the IPs that you want to ban**:

```
192.168.0.1 1
192.168.0.4 1
10.119.35.8 1
...
...
```

3 - Bounce your Apache process (since you have changed `httpd.conf`)

4 - Finally put this code in your `.htaccess` under your `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if IP is found in ipmap then return Forbidden error
RewriteCond ${ipmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} ^1$
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out. RewriteMap also has more nice  features e.g. letting you run a SQL or your script directly from .htaccess.