# prevent directory access using setenvif

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to use `SetEnvIf` to block directory access to specific ip addresses.
here is what i came up with.

```
<Directory /main>
order allow,deny
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^(2|5|6)\. banned [OR]
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^(7|8|9)\. banned
allow from all
deny from env=banned
</Directory>
```

the `(2|5|6)\.` and `(7|8|9)\.` are wildcarded ip address examples,
I am trying to prevent those ranges from accessing the `main` directory on my server.
but not sure if  the `[OR]` and the wildcarded ip addresses will work.
Also how can i redirect the `banned` to `http://officeofstrategicinfluence.com/spam/` 
instead of just denying or blocking them?

Comment: You don't need the `[OR]`, both rules will happily be applied if they match, nothing will unset a previous match.

Comment: BTW: [this question & answer may be of use to you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852557/use-rewritecond-based-on-environment-variable-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[OR]` cannot be used like the way you have used but it can be used as per the regex syntax. Try this code:

```
<Directory /main>
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^(2|5|6|7|8|9)\. banned

order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from env=banned
</Directory>
```

Also note that `<Directory>` directive only works in Apache config not in `.htaccess`

**UPDATE:** As per comments, you can use this rewrite rule in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(2|5|6|7|8|9)\.
RewriteRule ^main(/|$) http://officeofstrategicinfluence.com/spam/ [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: is there an alternative to using `<directory>` for the `htaccess` ?and is there a way to force a redirect with it instead of just denying?

Comment: i do not think i have access to my http_config file for RewriteMap, just htaccess. also confused how to add the redirect of `http://officeofstrategicinfluence.com/spam/` to your code.

Comment: I didn't even mention `RewriteMap` anywhere in my answer. And clarify what you want to do with `http://officeofstrategicinfluence.com/spam/`? Do you want to redirect `/main/` to this URL?

Comment: to clarify what i want to do, for any ip addresses matching `(2|5|6|7|8|9)\.` when they try to go to `/main/ ` they get redirected to `http://officeofstrategicinfluence.com/spam/'.  also i checked with host they say the RewriteMap is enabled should it be needed.

Comment: ok the reason  i mentioned RewriteMap was because its referenced when i looked up  `ipmap:` and was not sure if it was relevant to the code or not.

Comment: That is not needed in your case actually.

Comment: could your answer on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662645/deny-access-from-ips-in-file  also be used with my question ?

Comment: What is location of that .htaccess? What was your remote IP? Is mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: its my root htaccess, the mod_rewrite is enabled, i added 24 (which is the 1st part of my ip address) to the `(2|5|6|7|8|9)\.` and nothing happens, i can still view all the stuff in `/main/` might it have something to do with `ipmap` ive never used it before.

Comment: I retested this code and worked fine again so nothing wrong with the rules.

Comment: I tried the code by itself, nothing else in the htaccess file and it does nothing on my server. i used "
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(2|5|6|7|8|9|24)\.
RewriteRule ^main(/|$) http://officeofstrategicinfluence.com/spam/ [NC,L,R]
 by itself

Comment: That is only possible if .htaccess isn't enabler OR in wrong place.

Comment: ive tried other rules and they all seem to work. something with `RewriteRule ^main(/|$)` does not seem to work for me.

Comment: that works perfect, 1 more thing, using `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(2|5|6|7|8|9|24)\. ` if i need a second row, do i need the `[OR]` ? or is it just `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(2|5|6|7|8|9|24)\.  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(2|5|6|7|8|9|24)\. `

Comment: Actually you need a `[OR]` for another `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}` line.